# How to decrease the height of the responsive Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a responsive slider in which i need to change the height of the slider images.I want the `height:860px;` and the rest of the layout should be the same as original.But i am not able to change the height of the slider.

Here is the basic css..

```
.skdslider{
 width:100%;
position: relative;
display: block;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

And here is the Fiddle that i have created ..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vikas13pandey/xouyqpqv/)

Images i have not added but it will all be of height of `860px;`  .

Please help me.

Updated :

```
.skdslider ul.slide-navs {
bottom: 20px;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


.skdslider ul.slide-navs li {
float: left;
background: url("image/slide-bg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
height:12px;
width:12px;
margin-right:4px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.skdslider ul.slide-navs li.current-slide {
background: url("image/slide-bg-active.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css you have the below code:

```
.skdslider ul.slides li img{
width: 100%;
height:100%;
border:0;
}
```

Here, decrease the height percentage and check. Browser's developer mode can be useful in this case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok i have tried that .Its working but other things like <h2> and <p> of the image is displaying down of the page wheras i want it to look like as before

Comment: It might be because of the position:realtive in .skdslider. Use absolute position and check.

Comment: OK Every thing as per your suggestion I have made it worked the way i wanted except the css that i posted in my updated post.Here i want this nav to show up of the screen.Also the height that i have changed is `75%` from `100%`

Comment: You want to bring the navs to the front? Are they getting hidden?